# Convert NSString to double - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am confused about converting a NSString to a double, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
//eg: NSString *string = @"0,50"
```

a)

```
double d = [string doubleValue];
// -> d is 0.00
```

b)

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber *num = [formatter numberFromString:string];
double d = [num doubleValue];
// -> d is <null>
```

What else can I try?
Why does it work sometimes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `,` (comma) may not be the right decimal separator? Try with `.` (dot).

Comment: sometimes it works with a comma; the string being used is automatically formatted this way when I convert a double to a NSString elsewhere, so how would I be able to convert a double to a string with the dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` `,`(comma)  is used to separate groups of digits (thousands, millions, etc) not for the decimal point. This is much more a matter of locale. Use a locale for which it is the standard decimal point.

---EDIT---

A locale is a language setting of a given environment and is used to present many values as strings (or the converse). So try to use a locale that uses `,` as the decimal point (for example `fr`for French). `NSNumberFormatter` have a property named `locale` to modify the conversion strategy.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "using a locale"?

Comment: @BesfortAbazi I didn't want to give you a swift example but Ashley did.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal numbers can use either a `,` or `.` as the decimal separator, depending on the locale. You need to make sure the formatter's locale matches the format of the string you're converting.

This example is in Swift, but the idea is the same…

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let string1 = "1.3"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
formatter.number(from: string1)
// returns 1.3 (as UK uses '.' for decimal)

let string2 = "1,3"
formatter.number(from: string2)
// returns nil (as formatter doesn't recognise the ','

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
formatter.number(from: string2)
// returns 1.3 (as France uses '.' for decimal)
```

Alternatively, you can set the `decimalSeparator` yourself

```
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
```